# START_NOT_STICKY cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to stop my service from restarting itself by using the following:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I'm getting an error "START_NOT_STICKY cannot be resolved to a variable" and I saw another question about this and how it needs to be a service not an activity. I have

```
public class wd_locationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
```

Is this going to make a difference? or what else could be causing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what else could be causing this?

My guess is that you are targetting Android v1.6 (API 4) and the `START_NOT_STICKY` constant was added in API 5 (Android v2.0, I think).

If that's the case, you'll need to change the target SDK version of your app to only support v2.0+

Comment: @jgelderloos : Don't worry, I've been caught out by API versions like that too and seen plenty of other questions here on SO solved the same way.